# What do you call the "leg section" equivalent to "sleeve"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, terminology

> **[sleeve](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sleeve?q=sleeve)**: a part of a piece of clothing that covers all or part of your arm
>
> *a dress with short/long sleeves*
>
> *Dan rolled up his sleeves and washed his hands.*

Source: Oxford Learner's Dictionary

---

Now, what do you call "**a part of a piece of clothing that covers all or part of your leg**"?

Normally, people say **“the legs** of your pants, shorts” etc.

Is it common to say "**put your leg through the left leg of your pants**"? but then we have to repeat the word "leg" twice, which is a little cumbersome.

Comment: There isn't any other word for it. As a Brit I would say _trouser-leg_ if the context wasn't clear.. In your sentence, you could say 'left side of your pants'  if you want to avoid repeating 'leg'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is:

> [**Trouser Leg**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trouser+leg) -  the leg of a pair of trousers

I know you were probably hoping for a one word answer, but I don't believe there is one.

Note that in the US, you may use **"pant leg"** instead.

---

The following sounds most natural to me:

> Put your leg through your left trouser leg